# Ubuntu Touch with Meizu MX 5

Tags: ubuntu-touch, smartphone

I'm thinking about buying a Meizu MX 5 smartphone and installing ubuntu touch on it. I read somewhere it should fit, but I couldn't find any definitive answer, yet. So I'm wondering, if anyone here has already tried it out and could tell me, if ubuntu touch works fine on a Meizu MX 5.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

It works well , but it's not 'fully integrated' yet.

You can find out more at https://devices.ubports.com/#/

Note that the Nexus 6 isn't available yet.
The Fairphone2 should be along in 2/3 months,
and the Nexus 10 isn't a real option either.

Are you in the US ?
https://youtu.be/pe9QCZKJYOQ?t=55m38s

Comment: Wow, that was fast, thanx! The Nexus 5 seems to be a good alternative, but it also seems, that the Meizu MX 5 has the better hardware, I'm not sure, yet. No I'm in Germany. "It's not fully integrated yet" would mean, that not all functions of the phone (f. ex. the fingerprint recognition) would work with Ubuntu Touch?

Comment: https://archive.fo/7W2PQ