# Can I install Ubuntu Touch on Meizu MX 5

Tags: system-installation, ubuntu-touch, meizu-mx4

Is there a way to install Ubuntu Touch on Meizu MX5? How?

Thank you for help! :)

P.S. I've found the same question on askubuntu here [Ubuntu Touch with Meizu MX 5](https://askubuntu.com/questions/733516/ubuntu-touch-with-meizu-mx-5) but the only answer there is confusing. It says it is possible and points to a list of supported phones where no Meizu device is mentioned at all ( https://devices.ubports.com/#/ ). There are no instructions there either.

P.P.S I'm tagging this question meizu-mx4 because there is no mx5 tag.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What hardware does Ubuntu Touch support?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/236276/what-hardware-does-ubuntu-touch-support)

Comment: Yes but I asked that question almost 6 years ago. Thank you, though. :)